# Is there any way to create bacpac file from ssms using code not the export wizard?

Tags: c#, .net, ssms, bacpac

I am working on a .net framework-based windows application and I want to export data from a database and then import it to the other database with the same schema.

Comment: I don't believe that's possible: the software that creates the `*.bacpac` exists within SSMS, not SQL Server.

Comment: Ah, [the docs say you can use `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.DacStore.Export()` to generate a `*.bacpac` from C#/.NET code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application#NetApp) (just not T-SQL).